# React: form building in a Rails-like way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I am trying to enhance an existing Rails application using React (`react-rails` gem).

This app has a form built with following code:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><%= f.checkbox :sets_expiration_date %> Sets expiration date</label>
    <%= f.date_select :expiration_date, start_year: Date.today.year %>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
<% end %>
```

I want this form to have following functionalities:

- When the user toggles the checkbox, the three drop-down lists for the `expiration_date` field shows or hides.
- When the user submits, the form data is sent to the server via Ajax for validation and persistence.
- When the validation fails, the relevant labels and input fields get surrounded with red border.
- When the form data gets saved successfully, the form disappears and a message appears.

In my first attempt, I managed to achieve the goal but I found that I had to write vanilla HTML code a lot.

This is a disappointment for me. 
Especially, I don't like to specify the `name` and `defaultValue` attributes for each `<input>` tag
like `<input name="article[title]" defaultValue={this.props.object.title}>`.

I also had to write rather long JavaScript code to create three drop-down lists for the `expiration_date` field.

How can I construct such a form using React efficiently? Are there any good plugins?